# How a google+ page manager link an app with the google+ page?

Tags: google-plus

I am a manager of a google+ page and I want to link the app created by my google account with that page. How I can do this?
Is it possible or not?

Comment: what do you want a plus one button or a badge?

Comment: go to http://www.google.com/+/brands/ and create a page just for your app then you will be able to create a badge or a plus one

Comment: I am the manager of page and want to link my google app with that page